How to upgrade flutter from 3.22 to 3.24 if alot of pub package only support kotlin <=1.7.10?
After upgrade flutter 3.24 , it say I should upgrade kotlin. Howerver after upgraded kotlin I found too many packages used not support kotlin's new version, some of them over 2 year not updated...
